# Un-Subdivide - Remove loops on one axis

Tags: uv, edges, geometry

Whilst trying to make some geometry I have inadvertently introduced a number of edge loops that have effected my model causing the stripey effect shown in the screenshot. Is there any way of un-subdividing on the z axis only to remove the loops? I would like to keep the zig-zag at the top of the bag and not introduce any tris if possible.[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: what exactly is the stripey effect, I am not quite sure, could you please clarify?

Comment: So before I added the extra vertical loops the geometry was smooth. I added loops to make a zig-zag effect across the top of the bag. After the loops were added the horizontal stripe effect shown in the first screenshot appeared. This is not what I wanted as it is supposed to me a smooth metallic coffee bag.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**
First you would want to separate the zig-zag part from the bag, select the edge using <kbd>Alt-Click</kbd> that you want to cut like in the picture.
[image: Select edge loop]
Then you can press <kbd>V</kbd> and move your mouse upward to rip the edge loop off.
[image: Rip]
Then you can select the vertical edge loops using <kbd>Alt-Click</kbd> in a pattern: select 3, not select 1 (It doesn't have to be 3 and 1 but I found it to work quite well). Unfortunately, I couldn't think off an automatic way to do this, so you may have to do this manually.
[image: Select edge loops]
After you select all the edge loops, click <kbd>X</kbd> and select Dissolve edges.
[image]
This is the final outcome
[image: Final]

**Method 2**: This is faster but it may changes the mesh a little.
Use Vertex>Smooth vertices and change the settings until you are satisfy with the result.
[image: smooth]

Answer (score 1):

"Unsubdividing" but only in a single axis:

1: In edit mode, edge mode, select an edge ring.  Ctrl alt RMB on an edge does that for me, but our interfaces may vary.  Here, I've also hidden two edges to act as "stoppers" for the selection-- you can do similarly if desired.

[image]

2. Use a "checker deselect" operation.  I generally use this from the searchbar.  Check the parameters, and play around with these; this can be a useful tool.  Here, though, we'll just use the defaults.

[image]

3. Use "select edge loops" operation.  I use this from the searchbar.

[image]

Finally, of course, we can x->dissolve edges, and I'll unhide my hidden geo too:

[image]